# How to optimize Nextflow in AWS Batch (SPOT)?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-batch, nextflow

I'm executing Nextflow pipelines using AWS Batch.

- `Managed` compute environment
- `SPOT` instances
- `SPOT_CAPACITY_OPTIMIZED` allocation strategy.
- Allowed instances in range of `.xlarge` to `.8xlarge` from families of general purpose or memory optimized (e.g. `r4.`, `r5.` `r6i.`, `m4.`, `m5.` etc.)
- relatively large max vCPUs (128 or 256)

As an example, after running the pipeline it is submitting 3 jobs, each of them with defined `CPUs 2` and `memory 8 GB`, but the AWS Batch is deploying for that 3 jobs way larger instance (e.g. `r6i.8xlarge`, so both memory and CPU are not the bottle neck here), that is being utilized at maybe 20% for all time.

How to set this up, so deployed instances are not permanently underutilized?
I tried to allow smaller instance types, but then jobs are stuck as `RUNNABLE` and nothing moves for hours.

I tried executing the pipeline with various `--max_cpus` `max_memory` but also I don't see any effect here.
What am I doing wrong here?

**EDIT:**

According to suggestions, I setup three CEs and attached them in the following order to job queue (see config below):

- with max `.2xlarge` instances, max 64 vCPUs
- with max `.8xlarge` instances, max 128 vCPUs
- `optimal`, max 256 vCPUs

I have now 3 jobs stuck in RUNNABLE, each of them with assigned `vCPUs 6`  and `Memory 36864`

```json
{
    "computeEnvironments": [
        {
            "computeEnvironmentName": "ce-spot-optimal-spot-capacity-3",
            "computeEnvironmentArn": "arn:aws:batch:ap-southeast-1:088159696610:compute-environment/ce-spot-optimal-spot-capacity-3",
            "ecsClusterArn": "arn:aws:ecs:ap-southeast-1:088159696610:cluster/AWSBatch-ce-spot-optimal-spot-capacity-3-dbc12b72-6260-315e-a73c-4169455d2a70",
            "tags": {},
            "type": "MANAGED",
            "state": "ENABLED",
            "status": "VALID",
            "statusReason": "ComputeEnvironment Healthy",
            "computeResources": {
                "type": "SPOT",
                "allocationStrategy": "SPOT_CAPACITY_OPTIMIZED",
                "minvCpus": 0,
                "maxvCpus": 64,
                "desiredvCpus": 24,
                "instanceTypes": [
                    "m4.2xlarge",
                    "m4.large",
                    "m4.xlarge",
                    "m5.2xlarge",
                    "m5.large",
                    "m5.xlarge",
                    "r5.2xlarge",
                    "r5.large",
                    "r5.xlarge",
                    "r6i.2xlarge",
                    "r6i.large",
                    "r6i.xlarge"
                ],
                "subnets": [
                    "subnet-7d67d035",
                    "subnet-2912954f",
                    "subnet-c9a4d690"
                ],
                "securityGroupIds": [
                    "sg-a5c3b2e4"
                ],
                "instanceRole": "arn:aws:iam::088159696610:instance-profile/BM-BatchCEInstanceRole",
                "tags": {},
                "bidPercentage": 30,
                "launchTemplate": {
                    "launchTemplateName": "increase-volume",
                    "version": "1"
                },
                "ec2Configuration": [
                    {
                        "imageType": "ECS_AL2",
                        "imageIdOverride": "ami-0f8ea3f9358cddf80"
                    }
                ]
            },
            "serviceRole": "arn:aws:iam::088159696610:role/aws-service-role/batch.amazonaws.com/AWSServiceRoleForBatch",
            "updatePolicy": {
                "terminateJobsOnUpdate": false,
                "jobExecutionTimeoutMinutes": 30
            },
            "containerOrchestrationType": "ECS",
            "uuid": "5b44dea7-f980-3cd7-92dc-2dc64d0c821c"
        },
        {
            "computeEnvironmentName": "ce-spot-optimal-spot-capacity-2",
            "computeEnvironmentArn": "arn:aws:batch:ap-southeast-1:088159696610:compute-environment/ce-spot-optimal-spot-capacity-2",
            "ecsClusterArn": "arn:aws:ecs:ap-southeast-1:088159696610:cluster/AWSBatch-ce-spot-optimal-spot-capacity-2-ea6d28fd-495f-34bb-8ea2-1577fc961cf1",
            "tags": {},
            "type": "MANAGED",
            "state": "ENABLED",
            "status": "VALID",
            "statusReason": "ComputeEnvironment Healthy",
            "computeResources": {
                "type": "SPOT",
                "allocationStrategy": "SPOT_CAPACITY_OPTIMIZED",
                "minvCpus": 0,
                "maxvCpus": 128,
                "desiredvCpus": 0,
                "instanceTypes": [
                    "m4.2xlarge",
                    "m4.4xlarge",
                    "m4.large",
                    "m5.2xlarge",
                    "m5.4xlarge",
                    "m5.8xlarge",
                    "m5.large",
                    "m5.xlarge",
                    "r5.2xlarge",
                    "r5.4xlarge",
                    "r5.8xlarge",
                    "r5.large",
                    "r6i.2xlarge",
                    "r6i.4xlarge",
                    "r6i.8xlarge",
                    "r6i.large",
                    "m4.xlarge"
                ],
                "subnets": [
                    "subnet-7d67d035",
                    "subnet-2912954f",
                    "subnet-c9a4d690"
                ],
                "securityGroupIds": [
                    "sg-a5c3b2e4"
                ],
                "instanceRole": "arn:aws:iam::088159696610:instance-profile/BM-BatchCEInstanceRole",
                "tags": {},
                "bidPercentage": 30,
                "launchTemplate": {
                    "launchTemplateName": "increase-volume",
                    "version": "1"
                },
                "ec2Configuration": [
                    {
                        "imageType": "ECS_AL2",
                        "imageIdOverride": "ami-0f8ea3f9358cddf80"
                    }
                ]
            },
            "serviceRole": "arn:aws:iam::088159696610:role/aws-service-role/batch.amazonaws.com/AWSServiceRoleForBatch",
            "updatePolicy": {
                "terminateJobsOnUpdate": false,
                "jobExecutionTimeoutMinutes": 30
            },
            "containerOrchestrationType": "ECS",
            "uuid": "c331302a-8830-3b58-a914-dc54129e2a35"
        },
        {
            "computeEnvironmentName": "ce-spot-optimal-spot-capacity-1",
            "computeEnvironmentArn": "arn:aws:batch:ap-southeast-1:088159696610:compute-environment/ce-spot-optimal-spot-capacity-1",
            "ecsClusterArn": "arn:aws:ecs:ap-southeast-1:088159696610:cluster/AWSBatch-ce-spot-optimal-spot-capacity-1-6d15c4c4-8f8f-3081-b6af-38f5dfc47fed",
            "tags": {},
            "type": "MANAGED",
            "state": "ENABLED",
            "status": "VALID",
            "statusReason": "ComputeEnvironment Healthy",
            "computeResources": {
                "type": "SPOT",
                "allocationStrategy": "SPOT_CAPACITY_OPTIMIZED",
                "minvCpus": 0,
                "maxvCpus": 256,
                "desiredvCpus": 0,
                "instanceTypes": [
                    "optimal"
                ],
                "subnets": [
                    "subnet-7d67d035",
                    "subnet-2912954f",
                    "subnet-c9a4d690"
                ],
                "securityGroupIds": [
                    "sg-a5c3b2e4"
                ],
                "instanceRole": "arn:aws:iam::088159696610:instance-profile/BM-BatchCEInstanceRole",
                "tags": {},
                "bidPercentage": 30,
                "launchTemplate": {
                    "launchTemplateName": "increase-volume",
                    "version": "1"
                },
                "ec2Configuration": [
                    {
                        "imageType": "ECS_AL2",
                        "imageIdOverride": "ami-0f8ea3f9358cddf80"
                    }
                ]
            },
            "serviceRole": "arn:aws:iam::088159696610:role/aws-service-role/batch.amazonaws.com/AWSServiceRoleForBatch",
            "updatePolicy": {
                "terminateJobsOnUpdate": false,
                "jobExecutionTimeoutMinutes": 30
            },
            "containerOrchestrationType": "ECS",
            "uuid": "9a9c493b-4eec-3820-87a8-b86b93ab9341"
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the order of the [compute environments](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/batch/latest/userguide/compute_environments.html) in your [job queue](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/batch/latest/userguide/job_queues.html). The order of the associated compute environments is used by the scheduler to determine where each of the jobs will be run. So to ensure your smaller jobs are deployed to more appropriate instances, make sure the most appropriate compute environments are listed in ascending order.

Otherwise, I think just using a separate processing queue for the smaller jobs is probably what's needed. A separate queue would let you map up to three compute environments that are more suited for these jobs. You can then assign the job queue to these jobs using the [queue](https://www.nextflow.io/docs/latest/process.html#process-queue) directive. This of course can be done using one or more [process selectors](https://www.nextflow.io/docs/latest/config.html#process-selectors) in your `nextflow.config`.

Comment: Yes, I also use separate Qs as you mentioned. However as in the mentioned example I have only 3 submitted jobs (all the same type, same resource req.) and deployed instance is 3-x larger comparing to cpu/mem requirements of all 3 jobs combined. I will try CE order (with smaller instances first) but so far when testing - they are simply not utilized. Jobs are starting only after I add 2nd CE with huge instances, otherwise stuck as RUNNABLE forever.

Comment: @Art If the CE with the smaller instances is listed first, I would then suspect a CE configuration issue. What's the output of `aws batch describe-compute-environments --compute-environments foo bar`, where foo and bar are the two compute environments? You might like to add this output to your question.

Comment: @Art I will have to have another look a bit later, but have you tried just using a single CE (e.g. the `ce-spot-optimal-spot-capacity-3`) but with a much higher bid percent? I just wonder if that's all the problem is.

Comment: Embarrassing to admit that it helped after reducing greed and increasing bid percentage.  Let me check with the initial config of three CEs...

Comment: @Art Well they say greed is good, and I agree. IIRC, the docs say to start at 100% and work downwards. In my testing in the same AZ, I found bidPercentage of 40 works quite well 99% of the time. So you weren't far off at all.